# Matrix multiplication in Python, multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiprocessing, matrix-multiplication

I'm very beginner in Python. 
I have problem with matrix multiplication. 
I read matrix from txt file using list of lists (matrices).

When I want to use multiprocessing I have problem with divide list and use new lists in Pool function.

How can I fix this problem?

Please Help

```
def matrix_multiplication(list1, list2):
    A = numpy.matrix(list1)
    B = numpy.matrix(list2)
    return A*B

def counting(dane):

     left_matrix = matrices[0]

     for matrix in matrices[1:]:
         left_matrix = numpy.matrix(left_matrix)
         matrix = numpy.matrix(matrix)
         left_matrix = matrix_multiplication(left_matrix, matrix)


if __name__ == "__main__":


    matrices = []
    with open('sample-probka2.txt', 'r') as file:
        matrix_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
        current_matrix = []

        for row in matrix_reader:
            if len(row) == 0:
                matrices.append(current_matrix)
                current_matrix = []
            else:
                current_matrix.append(list(map(float, row)))

    print (matrices)

    counting(matrices)


    np = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print('You have', np, 'processors')


    matrices2 = numpy.array_split(matrices, np)
    print(matrices2)


    pool = Pool(processes=np)
    count = pool.starmap(liczenie, matrices2)
    print count
```

error from comment, with an attempt to restore formatting:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:  
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/pytho‌​n3.6/multiprocessing‌​/pool.py", 
line 119, in worker result = (True, func(*args, **kwds)) 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/pytho‌​n3.6/multiprocessing‌​/pool.py", line 47, 
in starmapstar return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1])) TypeError: counting() takes 1 positional argument but 61 were given
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
TypeError: counting() takes 1 positional argument but 61 were given
"""

Comment: It seems to me I should modify 'matrices2'. In this situation I can't use 'pool.starmap(counting, matrices2). I should change something, but I don't know what.

Comment: I would just like to mention that unless you have a specific reason to use `numpy.matrix` over `numpy.array`, arrays are typically the convention used, which may prevent some future heartache..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want `pool.starmap` in this instance. what it is doing is unpacking each matrix into 61 elements as it is handed to `counting()` which only expects one argument.

from the [docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap)

> **starmap(func, iterable[, chunksize])**
>
> Like map() except that the elements of the iterable are expected to be
>   iterables that are unpacked as arguments.
>
> Hence an iterable of [(1,2), (3, 4)] results in [func(1,2),
>   func(3,4)].

you could fix this in a number of ways, but I think the most sensible is to use `pool.map` instead, as it won't unpack your inputs and leave them as a single variable. you could also define `counting(*dane)` to allow a variable number of inputs that would be concatenated into the list `dane` (which you don't use within the function, but I'll leave you to figure out what to do with it..)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
 count = pool.starmap(liczenie, matrices2)
```

what is `liczenie`?  I don't see such a function in your code.  The error message suggests it is `counting`.

But in  `counting(dane)`, `dane` is never used.

It looks like `matrices` is a list of lists of floats.  Are all the sublists the same length?  If so, why didn't you read the `csv` file with a numpy loader like `np.genfromtxt`?  But that's a side point.

Does `counting(matrices)` work?  Besides the messed up calling argument, it doesn't return anything.  I'm guessing it's supposed to be doing a chained matrix product, `M1*M2*M3*...`.  `*` for `np.matrix` is matrix product, not element by element (the `*` of `np.array()`).

But that won't work; `np.matrix(alist)` is a (1,n) matrix.  It can't multiply another (1,n) matrix, no matter how many times you wrap it in `np.matrix` (why do you do that several times?)

```
In [25]: M1 = np.matrix([1,2,3,4])
In [26]: M1*M1
....
ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (1,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

What's the purpose of the multiprocessing?  What is is supposed to do that a single call to a corrected `counting` can't do?